# Do not fill p:inputText with 0 when binding to an integer property

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using,

- PrimeFaces 5.1
- JSF 2.2
- Java 8

When I bind a `<p:inputText>` to an `int` property, it automatically fills with `0`.
Here's some code:

```
<h:outputText value="Number"/>

<p:inputText styleClass="inputNumero" 
             required="true"
             requiredMessage="Field NUMBER cannot be empty!"
             value="#{myBean.number}"/>
```

`myBean.number` is an `int`.

Anyone knows if it's possible?

Comment: That does not happen. How does your bean `MyBean` look like?

Comment: @BalusC thats it. I'm using `int` not `Integer`.